# pasar array como argumento POST en el navegador e insertar multiples registros

Tags: array, post, insertar

vi muchos post pero no logro resolver lo que quiero, necesito ejecutar desde una app externa un archivo php, que reciba un array(son varias columnas con muchas filas, cerca de 12000 filas) como argumento post y que los inserte en una base de datos. No se si hay limites, si se puede pasar tanta cantidad de informacion usando _post

quise probar ejecutar un archivo php desde el navegador , pero no se la sentencia correcta para pasar un array como parametro

he usado procesos similares antes, pero enviando solo algún dato suelto
(por ejemplo /archivo.php?dato=juan), como para hacer una consulta o algo asi, pero nunca pasando un array por el metodo post

pongo un ejemplo de lo que necesito, tengo estos campos en mi base de datos (nombre,ciudad,edad)
necesito hacer un archivo php que reciba los datos y los inserte en la base de datos.
Serian unos 12000 registros que necesito insertar de una sola vez

enviaría desde la otra app un array ejecutando el archivo php, pasandole los datos

juan,  lima,  22

pedro,  madrid,  34

luis,  moscu,  44
......

agradecere si me pueden orientar. muchas gracias

Aclaro un poco mas
antes que nada gracias por responder y pido disculpas por no ser claro. Desde una app android, hago que se ejecute el archivo del servidor, como lo haria desde un navegador web //archivo.php?parametro=valor    el tema q ese parametro es un array.  No se si eso cambia en algo. ? Luego el archivo php lee ese parametro y actualiza la base de datos.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! basicamente, tu pregunta es: como hacer un post desde (? no lo dices) hacia una api en php (que lo reciba)... bueno... ahora...cual es el problema? no sabes hacer un post??? desde donde???? y es un proceso recurrente???

Comment: Claro que lo puedes hacer, segun tu ejemplo podrías enviarlo en el "body" de la peticion, podrías ser en formato JSON o formato CSV, analizas ese contenido en el archivo PHP y lo insertas en la BD. Que problema específico tienes con ese proceso?

Comment: O sea.. tu pregunta es como hacer un post desde una app en android? donde esta tu codigo de la app?

Comment: Por parámetros de URL no lo veo factible, aunque es posible enviar parámetros bastante largos, hay servidores y navegadores que ponen o establecen un [límite a la longitud máxima de una URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers).

Comment: desde android uso la libreria Volley, puedo hacer Insert o consultas  Select pasandole parametros al archivo php, y recibiendolos con POST sin problemas. He usado un archivo con parametros para hacer Insert  a la Base de datos pero pasandole unos pocos parametros nada mas. Como podria ser un login (nombre, mail y un par de cosas mas). Ahora necesito hacer un insert masivo a la base de datos del servidor, es decir ejecutar un archivo php que me inserte 12000 registros de una sola vez  Mi duda es si es esos 12000 los podrias llegar a pasar por un array o no o deberia buscar otra alternativa

Comment: Por parámetros URL no podrás hacerlo. Debes buscar una alternativa. 12000 llamadas o si te acepta varios datos, entonces llamadas con la cantidad de datos máxima que puedas pasar.

Comment: Ok muchas gracias por su tiempo